# SwiftUI Crash in ForEach Loop

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
        LazyHGrid(rows: gridLayout2, alignment: .center, spacing: columnSpacing, pinnedViews: [], content: {
            Section(
                header: SectionView(rotateClockwise: false, headerText: "Premium Store"),
                footer: SectionView(rotateClockwise: true, headerText: "Premium Store")) {
                ForEach(premiumStoreItems) { item in
                    StoreItemView(storeItem: item)
                }
            }
        }) //: LAZYHGRID
        .frame(height: 200)
        .padding(15)
    })
```

The crash is occurring in the ForEach loop.

If I comment the ForEach and pass in 1 specific item from my array, it works fine. However I need to display all my items in my array.

I am not sure what to do here.

The following code works fine.

```
 //ForEach(premiumStoreItems) { item in
      StoreItemView(storeItem: premiumStoreItems[0])
 //}
```

CRASH LOG (sorry I didnt know where to get it)

```
Application Specific Information:
Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0
```

------ FULL CRASH LOG

Process:               AppExample001 [3525]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/C93C2BE8-C23A-4813-9D6C-110E87786FFE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/40562FF7-7B66-4BE4-915A-5A2A35AD3EC2/AppExample001.app/AppExample001
Identifier:            AppExample001
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [2488]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [611]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-04-07 12:23:50.173 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.2 (18P4347)
Anonymous UUID:        5A68DF80-DD1B-1132-4597-BBC26C334627

Time Awake Since Boot: 7000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [3525]

ID   Vend/Dev
95f5 687f1002
Seconds Ago   ID   Type
6900.0   95f5 Attach

Application Specific Information:
Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0

CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (C93C2BE8-C23A-4813-9D6C-110E87786FFE) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone SE (2nd generation)

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00007fff2fc85004 *assertionFailure(*:*:file:line:flags:) + 532
1   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff572e9d24 ViewCache.commitPlacedChildren(from:to:) + 4020
2   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff571a1f16 specialized IncrementalChildPlacements.updateValue() + 1558
3   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff572be37f partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init(*:) + 15
4   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd78723 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 505
5   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd78bb9 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 335
6   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd7d85f AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*, long) + 523
7   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd8edc5 AGGraphGetValue + 203
8   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff572edac0 IncrementalPreference.children.getter + 48
9   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff572edb95 IncrementalPreference.value.getter + 85
10  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff572ede1c protocol witness for Rule.value.getter in conformance IncrementalPreference + 28
11  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd91907 dispatch thunk of Rule.value.getter + 7
12  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff570e9a18 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init(_:) + 56
13  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd78723 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 505
14  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd78bb9 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 335
15  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd7d318 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*) + 130
16  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff4cd8ee13 AGGraphGetValue + 281
17  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff57987807 GraphHost.updatePreferences() + 39
18  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff57458cbf ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at:) + 95
19  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff573f04e4 specialized closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 1316
20  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff573ed28e specialized ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 366
21  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff57a59c0e specialized UIHostingController._render(seconds:) + 46
22  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c117536 0x10c10a000 + 54582
23  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c1246eb 0x10c10a000 + 108267
24  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c11b91f 0x10c10a000 + 71967
25  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c11bc08 0x10c10a000 + 72712
26  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c11ddff 0x10c10a000 + 81407
27  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c11c274 0x10c10a000 + 74356
28  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c1134e3 0x10c10a000 + 38115
29  com.apple.dt.XCPreviewKit       0x000000010c112eee 0x10c10a000 + 36590
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff2010532f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20106508 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20112ff7 *dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1045
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2038fdbb **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2038a63e __CFRunLoopRun + 2685
35  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
36  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x00007fff2c257db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
37  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff24696cf7 -[UIApplication *run] + 912
38  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff2469bba8 UIApplicationMain + 101
39  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff5791abc7 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(*:) + 119
40  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff5791ab3f runApp(*:) + 143
41  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff5745212d static App.main() + 61
42  com.oneorangetree.AppExample001 0x000000010bfcaf4e static AppExample001App.$main() + 78
43  com.oneorangetree.AppExample001 0x000000010bfcafd4 main + 20
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2025a3e9 start + 1

Comment: What does the error say when the crash happens?

Comment: Added crash log @Cuneyt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForEach is unable to identify the each item uniquely,
make sure your data model struct is confirm to identifiable protocol

**try this on**

```
ForEach(premiumStoreItems, id:\.self)
ForEach(premiumStoreItems, id:\.id) // if you've unique identifier with the name of "id"
```